# Perspective correction via markers

Tags: image-processing

I have a webcam pointing to a big blackboard (a whole wall).  The border of the wall is cropped out of the camera fov, so I cannot use that as a guide for perspective correcting the image.  I was thinking to use 4 markers (AR-markers?) placed inside the fov and use those to perspective correct the image.  I understand it would be possible to detect the markers using openCV, but ideally this whole thing should run on a Raspberry Pi 0, so I would prefer a less intensive option if available.

What would be my options?

Comment: if neither the camera nor the board move, you can do that once and keep the information. -- yes, aruco markers would be simple to locate but they'd be overkill. 3D position and orientation for each marker? you only need a homography, i.e. four points in the camera's view. other marks would serve too. it's ok to prototype with whatever's handy (that includes aruco).

Comment: Well, yes if the camera did not move that would be of course a solution.  However, the camera is mounted on a movable arm, so i would need a way to detect the position of the markers for each picture taken…

Comment: before you judge things to be "too slow" or anything like that, you should try them. you can't know how they perform before you try. talk is cheap. this task requires a theoretical minimum of computation. I don't know if your choice of processor is enough. it might be. if it's not, your choice is wrong. maybe you need an entirely different approach. that's engineering. you don't get that for free. this site is for concrete programming issues. you get brainstorming for free sometimes but that's beyond gratis.

Comment: that's a good point!